# Can I make office 365 file handler for existing file format? (docx, xlsx, pptx, ...)

Tags: office365, add-in, office-addins, filehandler

in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/using-cross-suite-apps), it says

> File handlers are a new type of Office add-in that integrate non-Microsoft file types into Office 365 in the same way that that Office file types are.

and 'docx' is Microsoft file type, so I think I can't make file handler for 'docx' format.

and I also did a simple test (that failed).
but why I'm asking here is because I can't sure I did everything correctly.

Is it possible?
whether it is or not, is it official state of Microsoft? are there any page links?

what I tested:
1. made a addin in azure active directory page.
2. in http: //addinsmanager.azurewebsites.net/, set its extension to docx and all urls to fake urls.
3. uploaded docx file to onedrive.
4. it still shows docx icon well, and word online is executed when I click the file.
5. I found "docx file" menu is added to new file drop down menu. when I click it, I'm sended to fake url. but, when I come back to onedrive and click the same file again, word online is executed. (instead of fake url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct that because DOCX is a Microsoft file type you can't make a File Handler add-in for it.

As the link you reference notes, File Handler add-ins can only add functionality for non-Microsoft files, such as CSV, MP4, DAT, EXE, RSS, RAR, or any other non-MS file extension you can think of.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: then, is there any plan to support file handlers for microsoft formats?  do you know about that?    for example, google drive provide "open with" extension. so docx file is opened by google docs, but user can select another web app by "open with" context menu.

Comment: @Michael I followed the tutorial found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-file-handler-extensions) - but it seems outdated (although its last update date is Jan 2017) because I'm using VS 2015 and there are non-matching things explained there. And I registered custom file icon for `.encx` file extension, but it doesn't show icon nor open in custom file handler in my sharepoint. what's wrong?